# Sequelize error model is not associated

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models: userAuth and userFollow that I associate before sync.
The association is that userFollow has two foreign keys referencing user.
I did not use aliases but when I do:

```
userAuth.findOne({
        where:{
            id: "someid"
        },
        include: [{
            model: userFollow
        }],
        logging: false
    })
```

It throws error that says: [Error: user_follow is not associated to user_auth!]

I have this class method "associate" in userFollow that I call before sync:

```
classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                // ALTER TABLE user_follow
                // ADD FOREIGN KEY (follower_id)
                // REFERENCES user_auth(id)
                // ON DELETE CASCADE
                // ON UPDATE CASCADE
                userFollow.belongsTo(models.user_auth, {

                    onDelete: "CASCADE",

                    onUpdate: "CASCADE",

                    foreignKey: 'follower_id',

                    targetKey: 'id'
                });

                // ALTER TABLE user_follow
                // ADD FOREIGN KEY (follower_id)
                // REFERENCES user_auth(id)
                // ON DELETE CASCADE
                // ON UPDATE CASCADE
                userFollow.belongsTo(models.user_auth, {

                    onDelete: "CASCADE",

                    onUpdate: "CASCADE",

                    foreignKey: 'followee_id',

                    targetKey: 'id'
                });
            }
        },
```

Comment: Can you post the entire definition for both models?  You need to define associations in both models.

Comment: I did not define association for userAuth because I thought it would be enough.

Comment: I am getting the same issue when I try to include Attendance on my User object with the following associations. 

Attendance.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(Attendance, {as: "Attendances"});